# Connect Infopath 2007 to a list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, migration, infopath-data-connections

I am trying to create a data connection(data source) from Infopath 2007 to SharePoint Online. I have downloaded Infopath and using client version.

Below are the steps which I performed.

1. I have added a control - Dropdown List Box
2. I have created a new connection to receive data from a SharePoint List.
   Note: This list resides in sharepoint online.
3. I have given the List Name and also columns.
4. I have chosen the data source for dropdown list and selected value , display name.

Now, when I open the form in Preview mode, I see error:

```
Infopath contacted data source but failed to retrieve data.
The query cannot be run for the following DataObject: ABC
InfoPath cannot run the specified query.
```

I want to know if this connection from InfoPath 2007 to SharePoint Online is not possible.

Comment: Thought not specified anywhere, but I don't think Infopath 2007 can connect to SharePoint online... is there any specific reason you want to use old version of infopath form ?

Comment: I have a sharepoint online site collection which has been migrated from 2007. There is an infopath form. I am able to open the form using client(infopath). Unable to refresh the connections.

Comment: Are there any resources / links provided by MS saying that Infopath 2007 will not work in SharePoint Online? I know they are planning to deprecate Infopath by 2023 but as of now, it should work. Right?

Comment: You also need to migrate your form to 2013 and publish....